# how to secure my secret key in strings.xml file in Android

Tags: android, secret-key

I am placing my secretkey in strings.xml. I checked by reverse engineering with apktool and I got my strings.xml file as R$string.smali when I checked in that file to see whether key is visible or not then i found my key string as

```
# static fields    
.field public static final secretkey:I = 0x7f0a0035
```

Is there any possibility of fetching the key from this id or any other process is there to fetch my secretkey from strings.xml file.

Comment: You should expect that there is somebody else who is at least as clever as you. So if you are going to distribute this application, anybody could do the same and discover your secret key in the process.

Comment: So there's no point in encryption etc. at all, because somebodys gonna be more clever anyways? Come on ...

Comment: using tools like apktool you can get all resource files from apk and I'm pretty sure that this include string.xml file too in clear way.

Comment: As Igor say, never store a secret key in strings.xml or in the code. You can generate on the phone or get it from a server at the first launch of the app.

Comment: thxs guys for replies, but i m asking you straight forward question whether key can be fetch from that id.

Comment: Why fetch based on ID, when you can get it from `string.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You should not store secret key in strings.xml

More secure options are: SharedPreferences or internal storage with mode write localy.
In most cases I suggest generate key on the phone. So every phone will have thir uniq key.

But remember there are no absolute security, rooted phone user can do anything with his phone.

Comment: as my algorithm was developed with a process of encrypting by combining two keys and a message which should be same exactly at server side. its a difficult process to decode, but the problem is to store one of the key while connecting to server in the application itself. make some clear suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Constructing the key at runtime. Bit manipulation / shuffling the key can be one way of doing this.
2. Have a customized encryption and decrypt the key at runtime.
3. If you can afford, you can get the key from a server.